# Math.pow errors in Java

Tags: java

I am 'obviously' just learning programming and I can't seem to figure out what to do in order to get rid if this error. The error is on the second to the last line - the line before: [System.out.print(+windChill);]

Here (written just below), are the list of Java-generated 'possible hints' for the errors that I am getting:

```
**')' expected
method pow in class java.lang.Math cannot be applied to given types
  required: double,double
  found: double
method pow in class java.lang.Math cannot be applied to given types
  required: double,double
  found: double
operator + cannot be applied to double,pow
incompatible types
  required: doub...**
```

Any hints or clarification would be most appreciated. Please see code below. Thank you in advance.

Shane

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a temperature between -58 and 41 degrees Fahrenheit and press ENTER");
        double temperature = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter a wind speed that is 2 miles per hour or faster and press ENTER");      
        double windSpeed = input.nextDouble();
        double windChill = (((35.41 + temperature - Math.pow(windSpeed * 16) + Math.pow(temperature * 16)));
        System.out.print(+windChill);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

`(((35.41 + temperature - Math.pow(windSpeed * 16) + Math.pow(temperature * 16)))`

[`Math.pow`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow) requires two arguments. You are providing just one.

Did you mean `Math.pow(windSpeed,16)`?

Math.pow is declared as
    `public static double pow(double a,double b)`
It returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument.

In addition you have an extra parenthesis at the left hand side.

Comment: +1 from me also.  I shouldn't have stopped reading after I found the first error.  :)

Comment: The thanks are nice, but I think Prasoon is happier if you accept his answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you're missing a `)` at the end of the line that starts

```
double windChill = (((35.41 + temperature...
```

You could also remove one of the `(` at the beginning of the expression after the `=`, since it looks like not all of those are really needed.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.pow` takes two arguments, in an expression `x^y` it takes first parameter `x` and second parameter `y`, but you're only passing single arguments.  Where's your exponent?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parenthesis here:

```
 double windChill = (((
                    ^
```

either remove that or add a `)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The Math.pow function needs two arguments, the base and the power. You are only passing in one value - the product of windSpeed and 16. I think you probably mean:

```
Math.pow(windSpeed, 16)
```